# printf conditional with variable number of arguments

Tags: php

I have a conditional inside a class that I would like to be transformed into a single `printf`. The only difference between `if` and `else` strings is the `<p>` tag with description and as a consequence 1 argument more/less. Is there any simple way to achieve it? Or maybe considering the alternatives, my current code is good enough?

```
if ( $add_info ) {
    printf (
        '<fieldset>
            <label><input id="%1$s" type="checkbox" name="eswc_settingz[%1$s]" value="1" %2$s />%3$s</label>
        </fieldset>
        <p class="description">%4$s</p>',
        esc_attr( $field ),
        isset( $this->options[$field] ) && ( 1 == $this->options[$field] )  ? 'checked="checked" ':'',
        __( $this->settings_list[$field]['descr'], 'extra-settings-for-woocommerce' ),
        __( $this->settings_list[$field]['info'], 'extra-settings-for-woocommerce' )        
    );      
} else {
    printf (
        '<fieldset>
            <label><input id="%1$s" type="checkbox" name="eswc_settingz[%1$s]" value="1" %2$s />%3$s</label>
        </fieldset>',
        esc_attr( $field ),
        isset( $this->options[$field] ) && ( 1 == $this->options[$field] )  ? 'checked="checked" ':'',
        __( $this->settings_list[$field]['descr'], 'extra-settings-for-woocommerce' )       
    );
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simplify it like this:

```
 $fieldset = '<fieldset>
        <label><input id="%1$s" type="checkbox" name="eswc_settingz[%1$s]" value="1" %2$s />%3$s</label>
    </fieldset>';
 $fieldset .= $add_info ? '<p class="description">%4$s</p>' : '';

 printf (
    $fieldset ,
    esc_attr( $field ),
    isset( $this->options[$field] ) && ( 1 == $this->options[$field] )  ? 'checked="checked" ':'',
    __( $this->settings_list[$field]['descr'], 'extra-settings-for-woocommerce' ),
    __( $this->settings_list[$field]['info'], 'extra-settings-for-woocommerce' )     
 );
```

Comment: The `printf` in your answer is missing the 4th argument. I added the line `$info = $add_info ? __( $this->settings_list[$field]['info'], 'extra-settings-for-woocommerce' ) : '';` and then used `$info` as the last argument. I tested it and php doesn't care that the argument is an empty string and isn't used anywhere in the HTML string. Your answer seems more flexible and clean than the other one, so once you correct it, I'll be able to accept it.

Comment: @Ryszard Jędraszyk I added the missing 4th argument, thanks for pointing out my mistake.

Answer (score 2):

Since the bit you're adding comes after everything else (not merged into the middle or anything which would make it more complex), how about simply having a second printf statement to add only the extra part, when needed?

It doesn't result in a single printf statement, but it does mean you won't have any repetition in your code, which I think was probably your main concern.

e.g.

```
printf (
        '<fieldset>
            <label><input id="%1$s" type="checkbox" name="eswc_settingz[%1$s]" value="1" %2$s />%3$s</label>
        </fieldset>',
        esc_attr( $field ),
        isset( $this->options[$field] ) && ( 1 == $this->options[$field] )  ? 'checked="checked" ':'',
        __( $this->settings_list[$field]['descr'], 'extra-settings-for-woocommerce' )    
); 

if ( $add_info ) {
  printf (
          '<p class="description">%1$s</p>',
           __( $this->settings_list[$field]['info'], 'extra-settings-for-woocommerce' )
  );
}
```